# Docker image is not come up with all the layers after pushing it to aws-ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have an docker image let's say `product-test:latest`. Which is running in all my environments without any hurdle.But when I am pushing it to `amazon-ecr` and pulling it to my `amazon ec2` instances and try to start the container with `product-test`. It's throws error like missing `zip` files of my product binaries in `/tmp/product-*.zip`. when I try to compare history(`docker history product-test:latest`) of both the images means `ec2` and my local `dev` server. I get to know that there are lots of `layers` missing.

Here is snippet of my `Dockerfile` through which I am creating this image.

```
MAINTAINER chintanthakar510@gmail.com

ARG binaries

COPY $binaries/.m2  /root/
ADD $binaries/product-*.zip /tmp/
```

I have also tried with `docker save -o product-test_latest.tar product-test:latest` and on `Amazon ec2` and load that image with `docker load --input /home/centos/product-test_latest.tar` but still facing the same issues. There are few things in my docker images are not coming to my amazon instance.It's really strange issue I am facing.

Amazon EC2 : `docker --version: 1.12.6, build ec8512b/1.12.6`

OS :`CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`

My local Dev server : `docker --version: 1.13.1-cs2, build ad32da7`

OS :`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)`

What should be the possible issue where I should check? It will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `docker save` and `docker load` commands to manage Docker images is not a recommended way. If you’re keen on [security](https://blog.aquasec.com/docker-security-best-practices) and don’t want to push your images to Docker Hub, then consider creating a private Docker repository or push images to ECR. The created TAR file flattened and missed some meta-data.

Best practice will be:

- Create a Private Docker registry or use ECR
- Build a Docker image with your static files and any custom binaries
- Push the Docker image to your private registry or ECR
- On EC2, pull the image from Private Docker registry or ECR.

In this way you avoid Docker filesystem layer issues encountered when using `docker save` and `docker load` commands.